# In a Bash script, how can I exit the entire script and return the success

Tags: jenkins, sh

I am writing jenkins jobs and added multiple shells in single job. On certain condition, at one shell i want to terminate the script with success and don't execute other shells.

I tried with exit 0 -> Job Success but it is executing the other shells.
exit 1 doesn't work for me as it causing the job failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using pipeline. There are throw/catch capablities for groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create wrapper script which will execute one by one all your scripts. And check after execution of particular script if return code is `0` and if yes exit this wrapper script. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/script1
/path/to/script2
#script3 is this in question
/path/to/script3
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then exit 0
else /path/to/script4
fi
```

Comment: But exit 1 cause failed jenkins job. We don't want this happen.Also it shouldn't  execute /path/to/script4

Comment: @AbhiramReddy will correct it. And if script3 return 0 script4 will not be executed

Comment: I tried with return 0 but getting "return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script" error message. Thanks inadvance for your help

Comment: @AbhiramReddy, return is used in different cases. you should use `exit`

Comment: Yes. exit 0 causes my next scripts executable and exit 1 causes jenkins job failed.